# symfony2 route with optional GET parameters

Tags: symfony, routes

My url must looks like:

```
http://example.com/search/1/?cmp_name=&cmp_city=&cmp_category=&cmp_code=&cmp_vat=&cmp_address=&cmp_emp_from=&cmp_emp_till=&cmp_return_from=&cmp_return_till=&search_only_name=1
```

How to write route for this url ?

What I try:

```
search:
    pattern: /search/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:search }
    options:
        expose: true
```

But getting error:

```
No route found for "GET /search/1/" (from "http://example.com:8000/")
```

What is wrong with my route ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is that the pattern of your route definition doesn't match your url because of the additional `/` at the end of your url.

This should match,

```
http://example.com/search/1?param1=value1&param2=value2&...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
search:
    path:      /search/{page}/
    defaults:  { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:search, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
```